# Path file not found

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jekyll

I'm trying to use some jQuery code in Jekyll, but I have this error in my console:

> [2020-11-18 15:15:40] ERROR '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' not found.
> [2020-11-18 15:15:40] ERROR '/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js' not found.

This is my code:

```
<script src="{{'/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
<script src="{{'/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
```

I also tried:

```
<script src="{{'../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
<script src="{{'../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>
```

My config file :

```
# Site settings
# http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/
title: Datalab Project
email: meryem.achemlal@alterway.fr
description:  Datalab Project
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
# twitter_username: tweetpressfr
github_username:  mery92

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
sass:
    load_paths:
        - _sass
        - node_modules
        - assets/css
exclude: []
```

Please take a look at the screenshot too

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxRLO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5NFI.png)

Comment: Have you tried `./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` and `./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js` ?

Comment: yes, same problem

Comment: You haven't shown us your server configuration. Why should those URLs resolve correctly?

Comment: Are these files exists in the directory?

Comment: @Quentin i added, please check my post

Comment: @AdamP. yes i added a screenshot

Comment: remove the first / or add a . if the  file is in same level (i dont see)  if the file is in the layout folder, you have to add ..

Comment: Can you show the content of the path /node_modules/jquery/dist/ ?

Comment: @juanmajmjr i added it please check

Comment: @Frenchy i already tried this, please check the path in the screenshot

Comment: Can you try to add the attribute defer and the type?

Something like:

`<script type="text/javascript" defer  src="{{'../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' | prepend: site.baseurl}}"></script>`

Comment: @juanmajmjr still have the error :/

Comment: actually i followed this tuto : https://terminaladdict.com/linux/jekyll/bash/development/2018/10/17/Jekyll-Getting-Started.html

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: Even if in the guide the script tags are in the `<body>` sections, try to move the `<script>` tags to the `<head>` section instead.
The problem can be related with Jquery when finding the resources.

Comment: @juanmajmjr thanks that was the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `<script>` tags to the  section instead of the `<body>` section.

Your problem can be related with jQuery when finding the javascript resources or related to the order of the resources.